# Paste in vim stripping newlines from the pasted text

Tags: vim

I am copying large amounts of text from PDF documents into vim, but when you do a copy-paste from PDFs as opposed to say web browsers, everytime the PDF line breaks within a paragraph the copied text includes a newline. So when I paste into vim using 'p', I then have to press 'J' many times to collapse the newlines.

I'd much rather have a command that I can map to another letter on the keyboard that takes the contents of the copied text and pastes it removing the newlines. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
map <leader>xx :let @* = substitute(@*, "\n", "", "g")<CR>"*p
```

Change the `<leader>xx` with the mapping of your choice.
What this command does, it substitues the end of line charater (`\n`) with nothing (`""`), inside the clipboard register (which is the star register). Then it pastes the text from the `*` register.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced "" with " " and it works quite well. Apart from mapping to <leader>xx I mapped it to <leader>x but is there a quicker mapping? I'd like to map your action to the letter 'p', and have '<leader>x' map to what 'p' originally would have done, is this possible? Also, is it possible to get this mapping to work not only in normal mode but also in insert mode?

Comment: I don't recommend changing that default `p` key, but if you really want to do it, use this: `map p :let @* = substitute(@*, "\n", "", "g")<CR>:put*<CR>`, and then `noremap <leader>x p`. For insert mode, you need to use `imap` and prepend the command with an `<esc>`.

Comment: You're right, it's better not to map the p key to something else. So I mapped it to <leader>p and it works well `map <leader>p :let @* = substitute(@*, "\n", " ", "g")<CR>:put*<CR>`, but mapping in insert mode doesn't seem to work, I put this line after the above one, is it correct? `imap <leader>p :let @* = substitute(@*, "\n", " ", "g")<Esc><CR>:put*<CR>`

Comment: no, it needs to be `imap <leader>p <esc>....` , so the first thing it does is exit insert mode.

Comment: Btw is there a way to see whether a mapping you are considering isn't already assigned to something else? For example, I assigned it to '<leader>p', but how do I know that isn't already in use?

Comment: Hi, could you please suggest how I could change the following so that the contents to be pasted don't include the initial newline? For example, if I'm in the middle of a line and want to paste, it should continue pasting on the current line (but stripping the rest of the newlines as you mentioned earlier). Here's what I have so far: `map <leader>p :let @* = substitute(@*, "\n", " ", "g")<CR>:put*<CR>` (I tried removing the first <CR> but that gave an error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) for that. It provides `gcp` / `gcP` mappings that force the paste to be *characterwise*, i.e. all newlines and indent are flattened to spaces. It also has other, similar mappings to force linewise mode, or paste with a custom separator, etc.